# Conditional Formatting formula to compare two cells when one cell has a delimiter

Tags: google-sheets

So I have in column D QtyInvoiced and in column G QtysSent. For each row, QtyInvoiced is a single number e.g. 50. QtysSent on the other hand is of the delimiter format A_B_C where A,B and C are quantities. In each case, A+B+C would be the Total QtysSent.

How can I write a conditional formatting formula that compares (in the example above), the single value 50 in column D to A+B+C and higlights both cells in the particular row if they are not equal?

I imagine it requires using SPLIT inside the formula but not sure how to construct it to tell Google Sheets to compare the sum after splitting to the value in column D and then highlight both if they are not equal.

Answer (score 2):

try this out:

Custom formula:

```
=$D2<>SUM(SPLIT($G2,"_"))
```

- 

[image]

Comment: sorry i don't have any guesses on why its going amiss in your sheet!

Comment: Deleted my comment because it was my error (and before you responded)! What was going wrong was that in my sheet there was another rule applied to column G which I guess was taking priority over this rule above and hence cancelling out its effect. Once I removed the other rule it fixed the issue of column G not being highlighted.

Comment: cool bcoz I was really having a stare at the screenshot;)